# Find the equation of the line tangent to the following curve at $x=\pi/2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$ f(x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt $$

So far I can find the slope (which I think is zero), but I cannot find the term $b$ of $g(x)=mx+b$.

Comment: The function is constant, as you wrote it.

Comment: yes, but the term b needs to be defined right?

Comment: The graph of a constant function is its own tangent at any point. So $b=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$. If you want to compute the integral, it's another question.

Comment: okay sorry i see your point thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you meant the tangent line to the curve:
$$ f(x) = \int_0^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt $$
The way you wrote it was not a function of $x$, but a constant. Fortunately, the derivative of an integral is easy and your calculation of $0$ was correct. The $b$ value is then
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt $$
This function is notorious for having no antiderivative, so you must resort to approximations. Usually, the best approximation is found using Simpson's Rule:

($n=4, \Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$)
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt = \int_a^{b} f(t) dt$$
$$\approx \frac{\Delta x}{3} \Big[ f(a)+4f(a+\Delta x)+2f(a+2\Delta x)+4f(a+3\Delta x)+f(b) \Big]$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{6}\Big[ \lim_{x \to 0}\Big(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big)+4\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\frac{\sin\pi}{\pi}+4\frac{\sin\frac{3\pi}{2}}{\frac{3\pi}{2}}+\frac{\sin2\pi}{2\pi} \Big] = \frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{8}{9} \approx 1.412$$
Usually the limit is not necessary, but $\frac{\sin0}{0}$ is indeterminate.

This gives $y \approx 1.4$ as your final answer.

Comment: You mean $y\approx 1.4$?

Comment: @MathN00b Yes, thank you.